# Why does css for mj-button inside mj-attributes not apply to mj-button?

Tags: mjml

I am using [mjml](https://documentation.mjml.io/#mj-attributes) code to build a mailer.

I am using [`<mj-attributes>`](https://documentation.mjml.io/#mj-attributes) in the `<mj-head>` to handle classes and styles.

But for some reason when I use `<mj-button/>` inside `<mj-attributes>` it does not work like other mjml elements...

```
<mj-head>
    <mj-attributes>

        <mj-button padding="15px 20px" />
         
        <mj-class name="btn-red" color="#FFFFFF" background-color="#FF1761" border-radius="15px" font-size="16px" font-weight="600" />

    </mj-attributes>
</mj-head>
<mj-body>

    <mj-button mj-class="btn-red" href="...">Download PDF Version</mj-button>

</mj-body>
```

The padding styles returned are same as the defaults...

[image]

Even if I add padding to `.btn-red` mjml class like this...

```
<mj-head>
    <mj-attributes>

        <mj-class name="btn-red" color="#FFFFFF" background-color="#FF1761" border-radius="15px" font-size="16px" font-weight="600" padding="15px 20px" />

    </mj-attributes>
</mj-head>
<mj-body>

    <mj-button mj-class="btn-red" href="...">Download PDF Version</mj-button>

</mj-body>
```

It again returns the default padding `10px 25px` again!!!

So frustrating, the only I can change the padding on a button is by adding padding attribute to each single button, which is nuts!...

```
<mj-button mj-class="btn-red" href="..." padding="15px 25px">Download PDF Version</mj-button>
```

Why is this?

See live mjml demo of the problem... https://mjml.io/try-it-live/o_HKn3RTo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `inner-padding` instead of `padding`. [Here's the documentation for it](https://github.com/mjmlio/mjml/blob/master/packages/mjml-button/README.md). You'll notice `padding` is for offsetting the element, whereas `inner-padding` is for actual internal padding on the element itself.

Comment: Yeah, `padding` is actually margin in MJML. ‍♀️